# Creating a customized namespace in C# asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, namespaces

To preface, I need to say that I am still in the learning stagings of asp.net

I need to create a custom namespace where I can place my DataObject.cs file
The namespace is .Components.Data

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your class inside a `namespace Components.Data { ... }` block.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no folder structure related to the namespace? Meaning the DataObject.cs file does not need to be in a folder called Data, which is inside a folder called Components?

Comment: Nope - you can have whatever folder structure you want in the project, it's independent of the namespace.  If you add a folder and a file, Visual Studio may infer the namespace based on the folder structure, but you're not required to have folders to match the namespaces.

Comment: @CSharp: It can be, if you want to.  If it is, VS will automatically put in the `namespace` block.